# Difference between arbitrary basis and coordinate basis and Abstract Index Notation

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tensors, general-relativity

I am teaching myself GR reading [Harvey Reall's notes](https://gravity.univie.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/i_gravity_physics/material/teaching/rt2/SS_2016/part3_gr_lectures_2016.pdf) on GR (referring to pages 22 and 24 - not of the pdf but of the page labelling)
I encountered the concept of an *arbitrary* and *coordinate* basis.
What exactly is the difference between two?
And what is this abstract index notation all about?
We use Latin Indices to denote Vectors and Greek indices to denote components of Vectors.
But why then can one replace the Latin Indices sometimes with Greek ones?

Comment: I believe that Latin indices exclude the time coordinate and Greek indices include time, but I may have that backwards. This was the convention used in my undergrad physics courses.

Comment: @MarkSaving we used to have this too. But this is something different.

Comment: So perhaps there are some cases where we're talking about a specific non-time coordinate. Or perhaps there are formulas which can be proved using time-inclusive coordinates which can be translated into formulas that don't discuss time. You'd need to provide a specific example in order for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ok I am including the link to the lecture notes.

Comment: @MarkSaving I think I sort of understand it now after many readings. Equations with Greek indices are assumed to hold in that particular basis and when using Latin indices they are assumed to hold in an arbitrary basis. For eg: $\eta_a X^a=\eta_\alpha X^\alpha$

Comment: Conventions for various type of indices tend to vary from one author to the next. That said, in my experience abstract indices tend to use $a,b,c,\cdots$ and coordinte indices tend to use $i,j,k,\cdots$, though exceptions abound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One frequently encounters quantities which depend on positional coordinates, but whose numerical values are independent of the choice of the coordinate system. Examples of this kind are represented by lengths of vectors, the density of a material or the magnitude of the gradient of a temperature field.

The most important property of a tensorial quantity is the ability to form such invariant expressions that evaluate to the same value in all coordinate systems.

Let us illustrate this by an example. In a Cartesian coordinate system of dimension $n=2$ there lives a vector $\bar{a}=4\bar{e}_1+3\bar{e}_2$ at point $P=(\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2)=(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$. The components of this vector at $P$ is $\bar{a}^\rho=(4,3)$.

If we instead use a polar coordinate system at the same point $P=(2,\pi/4)$ the components of the *same* vector is $a^{\nu}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(7,-1/2)$.

What is the length of $a^b$? Surely it must be the same in both coordinate systems. To measure this we obviously need an impartial (invariant) expression that is valid in any coordinate system.

Unsurprisingly there is such an expression. Using abstract index notation (*ain*) the length of a vector is $||a^b||^2=g_{hk}a^h a^k$. We just need to transform this into the corresponding expression for the components in each coordinate system. For the polar coordinate system we have $a^\mu =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(7,-\frac{1}{2}),\, a_\nu=(\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}},-\sqrt{2})$ and

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & r^2 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad ||a^b||^2=g_{\mu\nu}a^\mu a^\nu=a^\nu a_\nu=25$$

For the Cartesian coordinate system we have $\bar{a}^\rho=(4,3)$ and

$$\bar{g}_{\rho\sigma}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad ||a^b||^2=\bar{g}_{\rho\sigma}\bar{a}^\rho \bar{a}^\sigma=\bar{a}^\sigma \bar{a}_\sigma=25$$

The abstract index notation (ain) is a convenient way to express tensorial quantities and form invariants without reference to a specific coordinate system. With some care you can convert an expression from regular index notation to ain when you are sure the expression is indeed tensorial.  Notice the difference between the *components* $\bar{a}^\mu$ and $a^\nu$, yet they express *the same vector* $a^b$.